# Plane Euclidean Geometry in vector space $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ and $SO_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

> Let us recall an important fact from plane Euclidean geometry. Suppose
> that $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ are non-zero vectors in
> $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $$\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}=\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}.$$
> Then there exists a unique angle $\theta$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix}
>  \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta
>  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1  \\ x_2 
>  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} y_1  \\ y_2  \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> In a slightly fancier language, we are saying the following. Let $x$
> and $y$ be as above. Let $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ denote the group of
> orthogonal $2$ by $2$ matrices with real entries with determinant $1$.
> What we are saying is that if $x$ and $y$ are non-zero vectors in the
> plane such that $|x|=|y|$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean
> distance, then there exists a unique $g\in SO_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that
> $gx=y$.

But let's move on to the next example. Let $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ be a $2$-dimensional vector space over finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$.  Consider the "distance" on $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$: if $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{Z}_p^2$ then $\lVert x\rVert:=x_1^2+x_2^2$.

**Lemma:** *Let $x$ and $y$ be a non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$, $p$ prime congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. Suppose that $$\lVert x\rVert:=x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2=:\lVert y\rVert.$$ Then there exists a unique $g\in SO_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ such that $$gx=y.$$*

**My approach:** I know how to prove the case when are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I have some issues with finite field setting.
I was trying to do in this way: Suppose $x_1^2+x_2^2=y_1^2+y_2^2=t$, where $t\in \mathbb{Z_p}$. I was able to show that $t\neq 0$ because $-1$ is not square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, if $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  Then I stuck.

**Questions:**

1. Can anyone show the proof of this lemma, please? I suppose it should not be difficult. I would prefer the simple via direct calculation.
2. What happenes if $p$ is not constrained to be congruent to $3$ modulo $4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element of $SO_2$ such that $g\begin{pmatrix} x_1  \\ x_2 
 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} y_1  \\ y_2  \end{pmatrix}$ is $$g=\pmatrix{y_1&-y_2\\y_2&y_1}\pmatrix{x_1&-x_2\\x_2&x_1}^{-1} $$

It is unique because there is a unique element of $SO_2$ such that $h\pmatrix{1\\0}=\pmatrix{1\\0}$.

The condition $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ is needed only to say that $x_1^2+x_2^2\ne 0$ ie. $\pmatrix{x_1&-x_2\\x_2&x_1}$ is inversible.

Comment: Can you show more details, please? How did you come up with such a matrix? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably if I plug in this matrix to my equation I'll get the result immediately. I was wondering to see the process how you came up with such a matrix.

Comment: I'd say it is because it is well-known there is an (algebraic) group structure on $\{ (a,b)\in k^2, a^2+b^2\ne 0\}$ given by sending $a,b$ to $\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}$, it is called a "torus" because over $k(i)$ it is isomorphic to $k(i)^* \times k(i)^*$, if $i\in k$ it is called split torus, otherwise it is non-split torus.

Comment: (+1 obviously) @ZFR Just calculate
$$\pmatrix{x_1&-x_2\cr x_2&x_1\cr}\pmatrix{1\cr0\cr},$$ and you will see the light. Surely you have seen the example of the matrix
$$\pmatrix{a&-b\cr b&a\cr}$$ describing multiplication by the complex number $a+bi$ on the plane (so 2D space over $\Bbb{R}$). This is totally analogous.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I can calculate but I do not see why you multiple it by $\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1 & -x_2 \\ x_2 & x_1
 \end{pmatrix}$. I really cannot understand the reason under it. I am just asking for explanation

Comment: Explanation of what? $X=\pmatrix{x_1&-x_2\cr x_2&x_1\cr}$ satisfies $X^\top X=\det(X)$ and the same for $Y$ so $YX^{-1}$ has determinant one and its transpose is its inverse, ie. it is in $SO_2$. Jyrki showed why $YX^{-1}x=y$, it is because $Xe_1=x$ @ZFR

Comment: @reuns, I guess you meant $X^{T}X=\det(X)E$, where $E$ is identity matrix.